# gem recommendable without sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, sidekiq

I am kind of new in Rails, currently I am using the gem [recommendable](https://github.com/davidcelis/recommendable)
. when I install sidekiq, yes it works correctly. But when I do not start sidekiq, it always give me empty recommendations.

I see the description in the readme

> Bundling one of the queueing systems above is highly recommended to avoid having to manually refresh users' recommendations.

What means mutually refresh users' recommendations? If I do not use queueing systems, what should i do to get the current recommendations?

config:

```
Recommendable.configure do |config|
  config.redis = RedisUsage.client

  config.redis_namespace = :recommendable

  config.auto_enqueue = true

  config.nearest_neighbors = nil

  config.furthest_neighbors = nil

  config.recommendations_to_store = 2

  config.orm = :active_record
 end
```

It may be kind of a silly question? But i have searched for a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below 2 lines are executed in Recommendable.enqueue()

`Recommendable::Helpers::Calculations.update_similarities_for(user_id)
Recommendable::Helpers::Calculations.update_recommendations_for(user_id)`

Comment: Yep; author of the gem here. Those are the two lines you need to run to manually generate recommendations for a user

Comment: Really thanks for all your responses! Sorry I barely logged in to stackoverflow since then.